# Breaking of infinite loop in turbo c

Tags: infinite-loop, break, turbo-c++, turbo-c

Whenever I forget to increment 'j' and hit run it becomes an infinite loop so what can we do to break the infinite loop in turbo c if I don't have the option of  'Break' on my keyboard?

what process we can follow in that scenario to break the running infinite loop in turbo c ?

Comment: Turbo C has been dead for around 30 years now. Modern IDEs have decent debuggers that will allow you to break out of infinite loops.

Comment: "I don't have the option of 'Break' on my keyboard" - why not, exactly?

Comment: Also, the best way to deal with this issue is to stop it from happening. You can do that easily - when you write a loop that needs to increment a counter, and you type your opening `{` for that code block, immediately follow it with the code that increments the timer and the closing `}`. and then write the rest of the code above where you've incremented the counter. That way you'll never miss incrementing it.

Answer (score 0):

Haha, You have to face it. The only way out is

1. Teach your fingers to keep clicking Ctrl + S every now and then so that your code is saved, progressively.
2. When Struck in infinite loop, the only ways getting out  are:-
   a. Terminating `Turbo C++` application directly.
   b. Terminating `Turbo C++` application from Task Manager.

   d. Pressing Ctrl + C or Ctrl + Z continuously may sometimes help, but not gauranteed.
3. Always, have an `if` block in a loop as a last statement to remind you that you need to check for condition before continuing the loop. You may also consider using `for` loop instead when you are sure at what point you need to teminate the loop and progress further.

Comment: Turbo C predates Borland C++ by quite a bit. It's likely to be the DOS one rather than a Windows one, hence Task Manager is not yet born :-)

Comment: Thanks for the help but none of these key combinations are useful

Answer (score 0):

Most of the laptops now a days don't have an explicit break key …but it doesn't mean that they don't have that function either.

So first thing you should find out that what key (or combination) has the function of break for your laptop and then you can try the same old way of terminating the loop …eg. ctrl+fn+f11

If that doesn't work then try to close the whole application with alt+f4 ….and in the worst case you just have to shut the machine off.

Advice …try to avoid turbo c ….( man this is 2024 ) ….it still supports some weird things. Try code::blocks …it is available on most of the desktop operating systems ;)

Best of luck

Comment: Thanks for the help Ezio Le but none of the above key combinations are working that loop still keeps on running and I am using Turbo C because in our colleges they have made it compulsory to write your program on Turbo C at the time of the exam of all manual code writing so I was finding out problems can come at the time of my exam so I  am just preparing myself for this kind of problems